# Combining async code with syncronous frameworks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, backbone.js

I'm trying to use backbone for "everything" on the server side (with Nodejs), and got stuck with doing a proper validation.

The problem is that backbone's validate method return a boolean, and the validation mechanics should be implemented inside of it, but with node these mechanics are asynchronous, thus the validate method returns before evaluating my code.

Here is a code sample that illustrates well my setup:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  validate: function(){
    var result;
    Jobs._withCollection(function(err, collection){
      collection.count(query, function(count){
         result = count > 1 ? "Job already exist" : null;
      });
    })
    return result;
  }
})
```

I might be able to improve this a little bit, but I'm not sure if this would work:

```
function _validate(){
    Jobs._withCollection(function(err, collection){
      collection.count(query, function(count){
         yield count > 1 ? "Job already exist" : null;
      });
    })
}

Backbone.Model.extend({
  validate: function(){
    return _validate.call(this);
  }
})
```

Especially not for a bit more complex situations where I use async for example, and the return value is set in the last callback of async, like here (this is obviously wrong as res is null at return):

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  validate: function(){
    var res;
    async.parallel([
        .. do stuff ..
    ], function(err, results){
        res = results;
    })
    return results;
  }
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't use Backbone with Node, for this and many other reasons. There are better object models and other libraries available for Node, that are built to work with it. Backbone is built to work with a browser, which is a very different environment than Node.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous validation is going to require some manner of async support, which for node means `validate` will have to except a callback. You'll need to subclass the backbone classes to support this, or as @Derick says don't bother with backbone on the server. Another mismatch you will find is that backbone handles success/failure callbacks with 2 different function like jquery does, but in node.js the convention is one callback with an optional error as the first positional argument. Thus if you try to use things like `Model.save()` on the server you will have to write small adapter functions all over the place to translate from jquery style to node style async error handling.

I have gotten Backbone classes working in node, but it requires these types of adaptions.